# connect visual studio 2019 to github

Tags: git, github

I can't get vs2019 connected to a github repository. I create a new project in vs2019. Then I add it to sourcecontrol and I can choose github. Login usinng browser works fine and all looks good. Then I can even publish my project and it will create the repository on gitub. After this the issue starts. When trying to sync changes it always giver met the error: Error encountered while pushing branch to the remote repository: Git failed with a fatal error.
Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

I'm totally lost. I have tried changing usernames, reauhtenticate, revert the gitrhub extension version, adding users to the project on the github site. Nothing works. Anyone has an idea what might be going on here? Using azure devops instead works fine.

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: Git failed with a fatal error. Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it finally. I had to create an SSH key in git and upload that key into github. I was under the impression vs2019 uses https connection instead of ssh but apearently it does not.

Comment: Visual Studio can use either, it depends on the clone url you give it